# AWS EC2 RHEL upgrade from 6 to 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upgrade, rhel, rhel6

Is it possible to upgrade from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7 on an EC2 instance ?

The standard upgrade path suggested by rhel [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-upgrading) requires that the machine is registered to receive updates from Subscription Management.

And the subscription status on my machine says `Unknown`.

```
# subscription-manager list

+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+ 
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 
Product ID:     69 
Version:        6.8 Beta 
Arch:           x86_64 
Status:         Unknown 
Status Details: 
Starts: 
Ends:
```

Has anybody been able to successfully upgrade it on EC2 instances?

Comment: I am about to attempt a "yum upgrade" and see what happens.  The AWS docs all say that their Red Hat instances include all necessary subscriptions and have the same Red Hat that data centers use.  Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible,Red Hat only support a few hypervisor and none of the public cloud is supported for RHEL6 to 7 update.